# Changing the fontsize of selected column in table

Tags: tables, fontsize, columns, arrays

I want to decrease the font-size of a selected column. I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rccl>{\tiny}c|>{\tiny}c}
  \toprule
  Name & Age & Sex & Average Grade & Subject & Grade \\
  \midrule
  \multirow{3}*{John} & \multirow{3}*{24} & \multirow{3}*{M} &
     \multirow{3}*{A} &
                Maths & A \\
                      &&&&Science & A \\
                      &&&&Arts & A \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
  \multirow{3}*{Mary} & \multirow{3}*{22} & \multirow{3}*{F} &
     \multirow{3}*{A} &
                Maths & A \\
                      &&&&Science & A \\
                      &&&&Arts & A \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

That generates a table:

[image]

Is there a way to do it without changing the header of the table (1st row)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

write

```
... & \normalsize Subject & \normalsize Grade \\
```